# count in hibernate create entity session

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following create service method that uses `spring data jpa` and `hibernate` to fetch a `mysql` database:

```
@Transactional
fun create(dto: MissionDocumentType): MissionDocumentType {
    // retrieve rank on existing entities
    val rank = missionDocumentTypeRepository.countByCategoryCode(dto.code).toInt()

    // save new entity 
    return missionDocumentTypeRepository.save(
        MissionDocumentTypeEntity(
            rank = rank,
            // ...other fields from dto
        )
    ).toDto()
}
```

The `rank` value retrieved counts the entity that has not been saved yet. It seems that hibernate session is already aware of the new entity at the first instruction.

Is it correct? If not, could you explain why? If yes, how can I retrieve the rank without counting the not existing yet entity?